# Forcing linq to perform inner joins

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to force Linq to preform an inner join between two tables. I'll give an example.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People] (
   [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [Name] [nvarchar](MAX) NOT NULL,
   [UpdatedDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL
   ... Other fields ...
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CompanyPositions] (
   [CompanyPositionId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [CompanyId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
   ... Other fields ...
)
```

Now I'm working with unusual database as there's a reason beyond my control for people to be missing from the People table but have a record in CompanyPositions.  I want to filter out CompanyPositions with missing People by joining the tables.

```
return (from pos in CompanyPositions
        join p in People on pos.PersonId equals p.PersonId
        select pos).ToList();
```

Linq sees this join as redundant and removes it from the SQL it generates.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[CompanyPositionId] AS [CompanyPositionId], 
[Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId], 
.... 
FROM  [dbo].[CompanyPositions] AS [Extent1]
```

However it's not redundant in my case. I can fix it like this

```
// The min date check will always be true, here to force linq to perform the inner join
var minDate = DateTimeExtensions.SqlMinSmallDate;

return (from pos in CompanyPositions
        join p in People on pos.PersonId equals p.PersonId
        where p.UpdatedDate >= minDate
        select pos).ToList();
```

However this now creates a needless where clause in my SQL.  As a purest I'd like to remove this.  Any idea's or does the current database design tie my hands?

Comment: What are you using? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Entities? Something else?

Comment: Does your model have navigation properties? If so, you could write something like `where pos.Person != null`.

Comment: I'm using LinqToSql, I've tried 'where pos.Person != null' and 'p.PersonId != 0' and Linq removes them. In the case of 'p.PersonId != 0' it changes it to 'pos.PersonId != 0' which impresses me even if it's not what I'm after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since PersonId is declared `NOT NULL` (and I assume it is declared as an FK to People) then I'm not sure how you could have a CompanyPosition with a person that is not assigned; and Linq can't see how you can eiter, which is why as you have observed Linq considers the join redundant.

Comment: That makes sense, the database I'm working with is a flattened version of a much bigger and complicated master. Only data relevant to one product is forwarded to this and alas because of such missing records there are no FKs, these are enforced on the master. In this case the the person has been unpublished so it's not pushed from the master. Ideally nor would the CompanyPosition but this is out of my control.  Looks like the db design is the major problem here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LinqToSql, you can use LoadWith similar to this:

```
var context = new MyDataContext();
var options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<People>(x => x.CompanyPositions);
context.LoadOptions = options;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to force linq to use a join. But the following statment should give you the required result.

```
return (from pos in CompanyPositions
        where (p in People select p.PersonId).Contains(pos.PersonId)
        select pos).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

ClientSide transformation:

```
(
from pos in CompanyPositions
join p in People on pos.PersonId equals p.PersonId
select new {pos, p}
).ToList().Select(x => x.pos);
```

---

More direct filtering:

```
from pos in CompanyPositions
where pos.People.Any()
select pos
```