# Force Linq to entities use inner join (EF 6)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a Linq statement like this:

```
IQueryable ActiveContract = (
    from c in context.Contracts
    join a in context.Abonents on c.AbonentID equals a.ID
    where a.ID != null && c.Hidden != true && c.Status == activeContractStatus)
```

It generates the following query:

```
SELECT 
    ...Contract properties...
    FROM [dbo].[Contracts] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[AbonentID] IS NOT NULL) AND (1 <> [Extent1].[Hidden]) AND ([Extent1].[Status] = @p__linq__0)
```

I've read this answer: [Forcing linq to perform inner joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243003/forcing-linq-to-perform-inner-joins)
but in my case `Contracts.AbonentID` is nullable and unfortunately:

1. Every other property in `Abonents` is nullable except `ID`
2. It is completely normal (in business logic) to have an `Abonent` with all properties except `Abonent.ID` to be null (so I cannot add any `not null` check to the `where` clause for `Abonents`).
3. I need only the contracts that are connected to Abonents.
4. There are lots of cases when `Contracts.AbonentID` leads to nowhere (no `Abonent` with such `ID`).

**Is there a way to generate something like:**

```
SELECT 
    ...Contract properties...
    FROM [dbo].[Contracts] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Abonents] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].AbonentID = [Extent2].ID
    WHERE ([Extent2].[ID] IS NOT NULL) AND (1 <> [Extent1].[Hidden]) AND ([Extent1].[Status] = @p__linq__0)
```

**forcing the check on** `Abonents` **existence?**

For example, if I need to find all phone numbers of an active contract by the contract's number (unfortunately, not unique, as there can be lots of contracts in DB with the same number, but hidden, inactive by status or just orphaned (abonent with that id is missing)), I will use smth like this

```
List<long> phoneNumbers = (context.Contracts.ActiveContracts().Where(c => c.No == contractNoToFind).Phone.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).Select(p => p.Number);
```

I want to state what "ActiveContract" is **once**, and use it throughout the entire DAL.

**UPD 1:**
I forgot to mention that the LINQ query is a part of IQueryable, so in fact, I'm not selecting anything at that point. Also, that's why stored queries are also not the solution. Edited the question. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: Could you return `c.No` but also some field from `a` other than `id`, materialize the results (a list, I assume), and then just ignore the `a` field?  It's not pretty, but it might work.

Comment: *It generates the following query* -- But that returns exactly what you want, doesn't it? It's enough to know that `[Extent1].[AbonentID] IS NOT NULL`, that's what EF infers from the join.

Comment: Any properly built database will have a foreign key that enforces existence given the existing non null check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like EF6 assumes a foreign key exists in the database and simplifies the query on that assumption.  You can explicitly check like this:

```
var contNo = (
      from c in db.Contracts
      where db.Abonents.Where(a => a.ID == c.AbonentID).Count() == 1
        && c.Hidden != true && c.Status == activeContractStatus
      select c.No).FirstOrDefault();
```

EF Core doesn't appear to do this, which is a better behavior as 1) you can have a Navigation Property without an enforced foreign key, and 2) SQL Server (at least) will simplify the query plan to eliminate the join if it only checks the existence of a related row and there is a "trusted" foreign key that enforces the existence of the row.

Comment: ``where db.Abonents.Where(a => a.ID == c.AbonentID).Count() == 1`` shows promise. I'll look into it asap. (For some reason we can't connect to work pc's during holidays).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using inner joins you don't need to check where a.ID != null since records where  a.ID == null  will be automaticaly ommited.

so you can make your where part

```
 where c.Hidden != true && c.Status == activeContractStatus
```

if you are still not happy with sql , just add this

```
 select c.No, a.Id).ToList().Select(i=>i.No);
```

I didn't see your classes, since you didn' t post them , but I guess this could be working too

```
var contNo = context.Contracts
     .Where(c=> c.AbonentId!= null &&  c.Hidden != true && c.Status == activeContractStatus)
    .Select(c=> c.No);
```

Comment: The OP wants just the records where a matching `Abonents` record exists, and apparently LINQ will drop `Abonents` from the SQL if no fields are retrieved from it.

Comment: @AnnL. why "apparently"?

Comment: I said "apparently" because I hadn't tested it myself: I'm basing this on what the OP said, and on the things said here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243003/forcing-linq-to-perform-inner-joins

Comment: That was almost 10 years ago, with ef 0.00001

Comment: Unfortunately the contract is only active when the abonent record actually exists. And there are contracts with Contract.AbonentId = Guid.Empty and just some Guid that leads to nowhere.